# How can I ensure mousemove works on window only and not it's inner DOM elements?

Tags: javascript

I'll try and keep it simple and I hope you can help.

```
  var el1 = document.getElementById('el1');
  var el2 = document.getElementById('el2');
  window.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
    var mouseX = e.offsetX;
    var mouseY = e.offsetY;
    var x = (mouseX + el1.offsetLeft) / 50;
    var y = (mouseY + el2.offsetTop) / 50;
    el1.style.transform = "translateX("+ x +"px) translateY("+ y +"px)";
    el2.style.transform = "translateX("+ x +"px) translateY("+ y +"px)";
  });
```

Simple function for a parallax effect but it fires on every dom element inside `window`.
So when it hits an inner DOM element the `el1`/`el2` snap to a new position based on `mouseover` being fired.

How can I ensure the `mousemove` works on window and not the inner elements of the `window`?

Important note: I cannot apply `pointer-events:none;` because an inner element has `href` tag that needs to be used.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Moe

Comment: héhé, I upvote this because it's a quite interesting question, but from a different point of view : You actually can not have a mouse event fire on the window directly. Even when the documentElement is explicitely removed from the DOM (with `document.documentElement.remove()`), the mouse events are still targeted to the document (except if the document is framed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[offsetX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX)/[offsetY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetY) refers to the position relative to the element the mouse is currently over.

> The offsetX read-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides the offset in the X coordinate of the mouse pointer between that event and the padding edge of the target node.

You are probably looking for [clientX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX)/[clientY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientY):

> The clientX read-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides the horizontal coordinate within the application's client area at which the event occurred (as opposed to the coordinates within the page). For example, clicking in the top-left corner of the client area will always result in a mouse event with a clientX value of 0, regardless of whether the page is scrolled horizontally. Originally, this property was defined as a long integer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Thanks for the simple yet thorough explanation.